# Cannot plot all data in a stacked bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot a horizontal stacked bar chart, with elevation as the y axis, and Europe and North America (data) stacked along the x-axis with the following code. Not sure what's wrong. Not all data are shown and the width of the bar is too thin to look at.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(EleRegion['Elevation'], EleRegion['Europe'], label = 'Europe')
ax.barh(EleRegion['Elevation'], EleRegion['North America'], label ='North America' )
```

[image]

The dataset is below:

```
0        0
1      100
2      200
3      300
4      400
5      500
6      600
7      700
8      800
9      900
10    1000
11    1100
12    1200
13    1300
14    1400
15    1500
16    1600
17    1700
18    1800
19    1900
20    2000
21    2100
22    2200
23    2300
Name: Elevation, dtype: int64 0     11188
1      9407
2      8801
3      8801
4      8692
5      7563
6      7134
7      6121
8      5077
9      3684
10     3330
11     1084
12     1084
13      918
14      918
15      776
16      776
17       75
18       75d
19        0
20        0
21        0
22        0
23        0
Name: Europe, dtype: int64
0     2657
1     1786
2     1786
3     1786
4      959
5      885
6      564
7      187
8      187
9        0
10       0
11       0
12       0
13       0
14       0
15       0
16       0
17       0
18       0
19       0
20       0
21       0
22       0
23       0
Name: North America, dtype: int64
```

///repeat to post/// I try to plot a horizontal stacked bar chart, with elevation as the y axis, and Europe and North America (data) stacked along the x-axis with the following code. Not sure what's wrong. Not all data are shown and the width of the bar is too thin to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `Elevation` as index and use [`DataFrame.plot.barh`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html):

```
ax = EleRegion.set_index('Elevation').plot.barh(stacked=True)
ax.set_ylabel('Count')
```

Result:

[image]

### Reason it was not working:

There were two problems:

- [`Axes.barh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.barh.html) accepts `y`, `width` and `height`. You were passing the first two, but the height was still the default `0.8`. The issue is that your `y` axis is in the range of thousands, so the bars were too tiny to be seen. You can set it to 50 and you will see them:

```
ax.barh(EleRegion['Elevation'],  EleRegion['Europe'], 50, label = 'Europe')
```

[image]

To avoid playing with `height`, what you do is use integers (e.g., `range(len(EleRegion))` as `y` and set the `yticks` to the correct numbers. This way, the default `height` would have worked.

- Another issue is that the second bar chart created by using `Axes.barh` requires the `left` parameter to really be "stacked", otherwise the second chart is just rendered on top of the first:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(EleRegion['Elevation'], EleRegion['Europe'], 50, label='Europe')
ax.barh(EleRegion['Elevation'], EleRegion['North America'], 50, left=EleRegion['Europe'], label='North America' )
plt.show()
```

[image]

That's why, since your data is already a `DataFrame`, it's more convenient to use `DataFrame.plot.barh` to handle all this automatically.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your code is more concise, I'll use it. But do you have any idea why my original code does not work?

Comment: @Elizabeth you are right. I edited my answer with more information. Hope it helps!